# powerline for tmux require reinstall each time

Tags: tmux, powerline-plugin

I use powerline for tmux on Ubuntu with `source /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf` in my `tmux.conf`. However, each time I start a new tmux server, I have to run `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` or just tpm install again to get powerline to show up.

Comment: Does it work if you start `tmux` with `-f ~/.tmux.conf`? That may help to isolate the issue.

Comment: no. It's properly sourcing my .tmux.conf, since everything else works fine (tmux resurrect, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Wait, are you using `powerline` from `tpm`?

Looking at the path you are sourcing *it's `powerline.conf`* think you are using the [official powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) but your information about `tpm` makes me doubt it because i don't think the current `powerline` has anything to do with `tpm`.

With that being said, in your `~/.tmux.conf` do you have this `run-shell "powerline-daemon -q"` before the **this line -->** `source /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf`?

Make sure to read the [docs](http://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/other.html#tmux-statusline) more though, I had lots of troubles getting tmux to work with powerline but powerline documentation is super! Just get in touch with it.